# Autofill records with previous values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, table

I have a track (point layer with date and positions) and some information associated to it. I enter this information when some event changes (Effort on/off or Beaufort goes up or down in this example). When I join the tables in QGIS I get something like this

[image: OriginTable]

I would like to fill the empty (NULL) spaces with the last values on the same field. Is there a way to do it in QGIS? I could export it to Excel, but I have a lot of tables with many records and I need to do it very often so it would take me a lot of time.
The table I need should be something like this:

[image: Results table]

Comment: I suppose that you are ordering the rows by the Date field. Is the date field of date type or it's just a string type field?

Comment: Date field is a `string` or `date` type when you import to QGIS? When you hover the mouse on Date header in QGIS, you will see the type of the field as `DateTime` or  `String` as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij8a6.png).

Comment: Yes, "Date" field is a DateTime field

Comment: And the table is ordered by the "Date" field beginning from the older value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a single expression in Field Calculator.

Starting with some dummied up data somewhat similar to yours:

[image]

Run the expression (see below), set to update the existing field:

[image]

Output is as follows:

[image]

The expression is the following:

```
with_variable('curdate',"date",
    if("beaufort" is null, 
        array_last(
            array_filter(
                array_agg( "beaufort",filter:="date"<@curdate,order_by:="date")
            ,@element is not null)
        ),"beaufort"))
```

By way of explanation, the expression:

- stores the "date" of the current row in a variable (not sure if this is 100% required, but I don't see how the filter in array_agg will work otherwise)
- builds an array of all of the elements of "beaufort" column with date less than the current one, ordered by date (array_agg)
- filters all of the NULL elements out (array_filter)
- takes the last element, which now will be the required value (array_last)
- only does this if the "beaufort" column is NULL, otherwise uses the existing value (if)

Obviously the same logic can be used to fill in other fields.

You could build this expression into a PyQGIS routine if desired, but the question didn't mention PyQGIS at all.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked perfectly. That's exactly what I needed

Comment: If it's answered your question, make sure you accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers